# TSQL get the Prev and Next ID on a list

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a table `Sales`

- `SaleID int`
- `UserID int`
- `Field1 varchar(10)`
- `Created Datetime`

and right now I have loaded and viewing the record with `SaleID = 23`

What's the right way to find out, using a stored procedure, what's the PREVIOUS and NEXT `SalesID` value off the current `SaleID = 23`, that belongs to me (`UserID = 1`)?

I could do a

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Sales 
WHERE SaleID > 23 AND UserID = 1
```

and the same for `SaleID < 23` but that's 2 SQL calls.

Is there a better way?

I'm using the SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the previous/next SaleID (or any other field) by using the [LAG() and LEAD() functions](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/) introduced in SQL Server 2012.

For example:

```
SELECT *, 
  LAG(SaleID) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY SaleID) Prev,
  LEAD(SaleID) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY SaleID) Next
FROM Sales S
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aeccb/4)

Comment: Very interesting, never heard before about LAG / LEAD. Now how do I just get the previous record based of SaleID 23 ...without having to put all the returning records into a "tmp" table and then extract the one that I'm looking for?

Comment: There are new SQL functions introduced with SQL Server 2012 for Transact-SQL developers which are called analytic functions. Some of these analytic functions are first_value, last_value, lead, lag, etc functions. You can check my SQL samples at http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/sql-analytic-functions-new-in-sql-server-2012.aspx

Comment: I read your samples, very interesting. I'm still a bit confused how to make sure I don't load the entire table first in order to calculate the LAG / LEAD ....specially if this table has millions of records. The goal at the moment is to ONLY get 2 values, the PREV and NEXT based on SaleID = 23. Any hint on how to combine those Analytic functions to optimize the actual stored procedure ??

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the PARTIITION BY clause in the [LAG()](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lag-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-previous-values.aspx) or [LEAD()](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lead-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-next-value.aspx) functions in the answer of thepirat000's, you can find the related previous or next records according to the SaleID column.

Here is the SQL query

```
SELECT *, 
  LAG(SaleID) OVER (ORDER BY SaleID) Prev,
  LEAD(SaleID) OVER (ORDER BY SaleID) Next
FROM Sales S
```

The PARTITION BY clause enables you to use these functions within a grouping based on UserID as in the thepirat000's code

Comment: Is there a way to get the PREV and NEXT of JUST the record SaleID = 23 without having to calculate the above in a table that might have millions of sales records?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the next and previous records only for a single row, or at least for a small set of item following query can also help in terms of performance (as an answer to Eager to Learn's comment)

```
select
    (select top 1 t.SaleID from Sales t where t.SaleID < tab1.SaleID) as prev_id,
    SaleID as current_id,
    (select top 1 t.SaleID from Sales t where t.SaleID > tab1.SaleID) as next_id
from Sales where SaleID = 2
```